# "There was an error completing your request" while testing bot in Actions on Google

Tags: actions-on-google

While accessing the project imported from Dialogflow over to Actions on Google, some of the things are not working.

- When trying to create new project, it is just stuck there in loading the popup.
  [new project error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHCEZ.png)
- While trying to access the "Test" tab, it results into an error "There was an error completing your request"
  [error while testing the bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNWZM.png)

Already tried sending mail to Google Actions support who suggested to clear cookies and cache.
Tried to clear cache and cookies but the issue still persists.
Also, I have only one google account added in the browser.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.